# How to add separator betwen number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script and I would like to add a separator (space) between numbers, e.g. `15000` to `15 000`

```
$.fn.number = function( number, decimals, dec_point, thousands_sep ){

    // Enter the default thousands separator, and the decimal placeholder.
    thousands_sep   = (typeof thousands_sep === 'undefined') ? ',' : thousands_sep;
    dec_point       = (typeof dec_point === 'undefined') ? '.' : dec_point;
    decimals        = (typeof decimals === 'undefined' ) ? 0 : decimals;

    // Work out the unicode character for the decimal placeholder.
    var u_dec           = ('\\u'+('0000'+(dec_point.charCodeAt(0).toString(16))).slice(-4)),
        regex_dec_num   = new RegExp('[^'+u_dec+'0-9]','g'),
        regex_dec       = new RegExp(u_dec,'g');

    // If we've specified to take the number from the target element,
    // we loop over the collection, and get the number.
    if( number === true )
    {
        // If this element is a number, then we add a keyup
        if( this.is('input:text') )
        {
            // Return the jquery collection.
            return this.on({
```

Comment: This seems a function extending jQuery, not php?

Comment: Please use [`Number.prototype.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) or [`Intl.NumberFormat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat) to format your numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I always use this javascript function to add dots in the number, replace the dot with a space or something else and it should work

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
  // Add a dot to numbers higher then thousand
  return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
}
```